# Polynomial regression in R with multiple predictors

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I wanted to use polynomial regression on my data, but I have more than 10 predictors and my predictors' name change on my samples. I also used linear regression on my data in the below code:

```
 model_lm = lm(gene_expression ~ ., data = donor_snp_sample)
 summary_lm <- summary(model_lm)
```

I used `"gene_expression ~ ."` in my code, but I don't know how to use the same format in polynomial regression. Can you help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: It's unclear what model you want to create exactly. Linear and quadratic terms of all predictors? (I think nobody should do that with 10 predictors. Use penalized smoothers instead.)

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous as to the specific model desired but here is one possible model where we independently take a quadratic in each independent variable.

```
fo <- reformulate(sprintf("poly(%s, 2)", names(airquality)[-1]), "Ozone")
fo
## Ozone ~ poly(Solar.R, 2) + poly(Wind, 2) + poly(Temp, 2) + poly(Month, 
##     2) + poly(Day, 2)

lm(fo, na.omit(airquality))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = fo, data = na.omit(airquality))

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  poly(Solar.R, 2)1  poly(Solar.R, 2)2     poly(Wind, 2)1  
            42.10              64.80             -24.13            -124.10  
   poly(Wind, 2)2     poly(Temp, 2)1     poly(Temp, 2)2    poly(Month, 2)1  
            89.41             128.16              55.40             -18.45  
  poly(Month, 2)2      poly(Day, 2)1      poly(Day, 2)2  
           -32.10              27.20              11.87
```

or write it like this if it is desired to see the formula written out on the Call: line of the output.

```
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(na.omit(airquality))))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ poly(Solar.R, 2) + poly(Wind, 2) + poly(Temp, 
    2) + poly(Month, 2) + poly(Day, 2), data = na.omit(airquality))

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  poly(Solar.R, 2)1  poly(Solar.R, 2)2     poly(Wind, 2)1  
            42.10              64.80             -24.13            -124.10  
   poly(Wind, 2)2     poly(Temp, 2)1     poly(Temp, 2)2    poly(Month, 2)1  
            89.41             128.16              55.40             -18.45  
  poly(Month, 2)2      poly(Day, 2)1      poly(Day, 2)2  
           -32.10              27.20              11.87
```